# How to create an HTML 5 Landing Page w/ Video Background

Tags: javascript, html, forms, video, ogg

I want to mimic Spotify's landing page here: https://www.spotify.com/uk/video-splash/?utm_source=spotify&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=start

I'm fairly new to coding but have created some landing pages before but never one with HTML and video as a background.

I want the same layout as Spotify with NO scrolling capability OR sound. Then I want to be able to click on the button and have a form that someone can fill out and submit. Not quite sure how to go about this.

TLDR:

- How to do HTML5 Video Background
- Create JS pop-up like form
- Where to get videos / format to work as a background

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HTML 5 WITH CSS FIX | No Jquery Needed or java**
I went ahead and designed some mark up for you so at-least you have something to start with. You can copy this code and play around with it. There are some key points in your CSS for this to work please keep this in mind and you will do just fine:

Your Embedded Video Has To Have A the lowest z-index

Your width for your video must be set to 100%

You must put !Important right behind the 100%

You must Use a Fixed Or Absolute Position for all your "divs"

If you do not you can not use the z-index option in CSS

Heres Your Mark Up & I hope this helps you!

```css
/* YOUR CSS */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* <-- this plays a key roll for it to work */
    width: 100% !important /* <-- this plays a key roll for it to work */
    height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

/* Your can customize any div how ever you want this is just an example */
#login {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:2; /* <-- this plays a key roll for it to work */
 left:45%;
 top:60%;
 width:250px;
 height:100px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(99,99,99,0.8)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(99,99,99,0.8)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(99,99,99,0.8)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(99,99,99,0.8)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 border-radius:7px;
}
#login a{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:30px;
}
#login p{
 padding-top:35px;
 padding-left:18px;
}
/* Your can customize any div how ever you want this is just an example */
#footer {
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index:3; /* <-- this plays a key roll for it to work */
}
#footer p{
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<!--Place your video right after the body tag-->
<!--Notice the id="wrapper" is placed in the <video id="wrapper"></video>-->
<video id="wrapper" autoplay loop ?wmode=transparent>
<source src="http://sectorvi.com/yourmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="login"><p><a href="#">JOIN FOR FREE</a></p></div>
<div id="footer"><p>Remember this will only work if you have fixed or absolute postions with enables you to use z-index. ~ Jonathan Bellavaro</p></div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

You can view in full here: http://sectorvi.com/stackoverflow-funitect.html
Hope this gives you a good start.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much! this is a great foundation for getting started! I really appreciate it!

Comment: It works great when I click the "view in full here" link you provided. However, when I copy the code into Sublime Text 2 and try to run it locally, I seem to have an issue with the login button and footer. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: can you explain the issue your having with the button and footer?

Comment: I copied in verbatim and it appears that the formatting isn't working properly. The "button" appears in plain text separate from the fixed video background as if it is part of the footer. I messed around a bit with the CSS but couldn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I created one and it worked fine in there. I'm literally copying and pasting the code.

Comment: Ok, Next question what program are you writing your mark-up with? i.e. Dreamweaver, note++, example?

Comment: I believe I'm having trouble linking the html to the css. I'm using Sublime Text 2 and I have my two files: index.html & main.css. I attempt to link to the CSS file using <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> and the button continues to appear in the footer.

Comment: I finally got it. thank you for your consistent help. I really am a beginner so that is why it was hard to get it together but I finally did it! Thanks again.

Comment: what did you do different?

Comment: I couldn't get the darn button to work so I ended up going to code pen and using a form instead of the button and ened up creating this http://codepen.io/funitect/pen/cDzof

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help and I hope you don't mind that I'm currently using your video as a place holder. I'm still trying to figure it out but how exactly did you create that video and host it like that? I'd like to get my own up but am not sure if there is a best practice for that?

Answer (score 2):

First, here's a **TLDR-jQuery-plugin-fix** that uses YouTube → https://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/

BAM! You could be dunzo right there, but if you wanna do it for reals yourself, you can use the video tag & place a div on top of it that contains your actual content.

> "How to do HTML5 Video Background?"

Start with the markup. Some notes:

- Three formats » MP4, OGV and WebM, one for each HTML5 Video codec
- Autoplay, loop, preload » use `<video>` attributes
- Image placeholder attribute, `poster`, displays an image during video load in case there's any delay.

So your markup will be something like this:

```
<video id="myVid" autoplay loop preload="auto" poster="/path/to/placeholder-image.jpg">
    <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="myVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

After that it's all CSS.

- Reset `<html>` & `<body>` margins & padding (probs already handled, but just in case)
- Set `<html>` & `<body>` height & width to 100% and give it `overflow:hidden`
- Set `<video>` with min-height & min-width so the aspect ratio can change (Note: you'll cut off a bit of the video on either side, but it's a background anyways, so it's fine)

And it goes:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#myVid {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
}
```

Some people use a div instead of writing rules to `<html>` & `<body>`. That's your call. Point is: overflow hidden has to be in the containing element while the video always has a minimum width & height of 100%. The overflow will extend beyond the window (hidden), but the browser will leave no gaps, spaces, or scrollbars.

> "Create JS pop-up like form"

What you'll want to do is create a JS modal. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery). If you think tuts are too long & perhaps a bit remedial, go poking around CodePen & GitHub for examples of what you're looking for. Use them as inspiration to make your own, like this one → http://codepen.io/0leg/pen/faIKJ. Don't forget attribution!

> "Where to get videos / format to work as a background"

So you have the format now. I would suggest looking around iStockPhoto and similar sites. Or use the above jQuery Plugin. Or maybe try **[Video Hive](http://videohive.net)**?

Comment: This is great - Thank you for your help in pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Video documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

I would suggest using something like [inspector in Chrome](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs132/resources/inspector/) to look through their web page - you can learn a lot by trying to understand their CSS/HTML code and then adapting it for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Before marking complete I'm going to see if theres any other responses but that is a great place to start!